# Is assignment to a std::atomic<double> variable guaranteed to be atomic?

Tags: c++, concurrency, atomic

I have the following scenario

```
// first assigned a value greater than 0
std::atomic<double> var=1;

//thread 1
while (True) {
    var = 1;
}

//thread 2
if(var >0) {
    //do something
}
```

My question is when `thread 1` doing assignment, is there a possibility `thread 2` sees `var` other than 1? Possibly some random number or zero?

It seems to happen in my production build with `O2` optimization(the above snippet is not the real code, O2 may optimize most away). It seems, according to the standard, that this should never happen.

Is my description correct, and the bug is elsewhere?  Or am I missing something?

I am using c++17, gcc9.3.1

Comment: "*the above snippet is not the real code*" Then you're going to have to produce something that more accurately resembles the real code.

Comment: Looks like that you intend to ask a generic question (I'm not very good at std::atomic, but) I think the answer is "it can never happen"; nevertheless if it's the case the question wouldn't be very practical. Providing a [example] of your code would make it a practical problem.

Comment: As mentioned by the previous commenters, the code you've shown in the question cannot possibly reproduce this issue. It is guaranteed that writes to atomic types are atomic. In order for us to be able to help you, you'll need to update your question with actual code that reproduces your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, writes to atomic types are atomic.  The bug in your code is elsewhere.

Because it has never been set to anything *other* than `1`, and the additional writes of `1` are atomic, there can't be any sort of "split read" where it reads some other value (as can happen on some architectures where the value may be written across multiple instructions, and a read might see the high bits but not the low bits).

This would be true even if the original number weren't `1`, as the reading thread will either see the entire write or not see the write at all (the definition of an atomic write).